# uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker in env config file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new with Ruby on Rails. After run the 'bundle' command for update/install, When i try to do `rails s` or `rails g mongoid:config` console returns this message that start with:

```
/home/myUser/proyect/config/environments/development.rb:50:in `block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker (NameError)
```

This is my Gemfile (Yes, i want to use MongoDB as the Database):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Mongoid as the database
gem 'mongoid', '~> 5.1.0'
# Use bson
gem 'bson_ext'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
#Use Haml for html
gem 'haml'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.x'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And the **config/environments/development.rb** file:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp/caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # Use an evented file watcher to asynchronously detect changes in source code,
  # routes, locales, etc. This feature depends on the listen gem.
  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
end
```

Comment: can you edit with the content of your development.rb file?

Comment: Sure, just added, watch now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr: Re-create your Rails project, providing the specific Rails version.

Often this occurs because you have a newer version of Rails installed than the one called for in your `.railsrc` or `template.rb`.

If this is the case, when you run `rails new my_new_app`, the newest version is used by default for the earlier steps of the process, but then once the template/railsrc version is installed, latter steps use this version. This causes compatibility issues.

You can verify that this is your problem by comparing the output of `rails -v` (in the directory where you called `rails new`) with what's in your `.railsrc` or `template.rb`. If they are different, there is an easy fix:

Recreate your Rails app, specifying the same Rails version from your `.railsrc` or `template.rb` in the command line call:
`rails _4.2.5.1_ new my_new_app`

Comment: re-creating your rails app seems extreme. I'm adding an extension that relies on an older version of rails after ~160 hours of development time.

Comment: Yeah, this is assuming you caught the problem early on. Which, as the OP states, trying to do things like `rails g` or `rails s` will cause this error. So most of the time it should occur before too much else has been done.

Answer (score 5):

According to [Rails changelogs](https://allmychanges.com/p/ruby/rails/#5.0), `config.file_watcher` option has been introduced in `Rails 5`. It allows you to have an auto-reloading based on your file changes. This feature depends on the `listener` gem, and you have it listed in your gemfile. But what seems suspicious to me is your `Rails` version!

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
# but rails 4 does not support that feature!
```

Looks like you've got a Gemfile (or `development.rb` config?) copied from another version of  `Rails` framework, another project, or manually changed your gemfile version to unappropriate state.

Two options I could suggest you are:

1. To change your rails gemfile version to the cutting edge one as follows:

   ```
   gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
   ```

   And `bundle` once more;
2. To remove `config.file_watcher` line from your config file.

Comment: first i installed the latest version and later changed to '4.2.6'

Answer (score 1):

if you remove   `config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker` it will work. It detects changes in the source code to refresh asynchronously, but it also depends on the `listen` gem and as you're a beginner, it will only cause trouble to you. Should work without it.

Comment: When i remove config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker this another happens /callback_terminator.rb:6:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `halt_callback_chains_on_return_false=' for ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)