# `<module:RailsSettings>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a ROR application I'm trying to stand up locally on a windows machine.  Since it requires passenger I am using WSL2 to run Ubuntu.  I've installed ruby (2.6.5) and made sure rails in installed (4.2.11.3).  I've run bundle install successfully, but every time I try to run a command such as rails server, rake, ect.  I get an error saying uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes.  From googling, there isn't really one answer for this.  I've tried removing and re-installing rails.  Removed railties as well, but the error keeps happening.  My suspicion is that it has something to do with me running on WSL2, but I am not sure.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978091/uninitialized-constant-activesupporteventedfileupdatechecker-in-env-config-fil

Comment: `CurrentAttributes` were introduced with Ruby on Rails 5.2. But you wrote that you installed Rails 4.2.11.3. That means we either installed the wrong version or you installed a gem in a version that depends on `CurrentAttributes` that is not compatible with your ancient Rails version.

Comment: Thanks spickermann.  I ended up blowing away my entire WSL install and re-doing everything.  I used rvm this time instead of installing ruby myself so that I knew I was using the correct version when I ran bundle install.